# Set URLSession Delegate to another Swift class

Tags: swift, urlsession

I am attempting to call an API to log in to a web site. I currently have all my API calls in a Swift class called `APICalls`. My view controller I'm using to log in with is called `CreateAccountViewController`.

In my API call to log in I create a URL session and set the delegate like this:

```
let task = URLSession.init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: CreateAccountViewController.init(), delegateQueue: nil)
        
task.dataTask(with: request).resume()
```

Then in my VC class I have this function

```
func urlSession(_: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError: Error?) {
    // Check the data returned from API call, ensure user is logged in
}
```

This function is being called when the API is done, but I feel like I'm causing a memory leak or something by using `.init` in the delegate declaration when creating my URL session. Is there a better way to do this?

Also, how do I access the data from the API call? In completion handlers there's a data response I can get at, but not in this delegate call.

Comment: Do you really need to use the delegate-based API? It’s an interface that you have to use if you need the rich API (handling custom challenge responses, etc.), but in most cases, the simple completion handler rendition of `dataTask` is *much* easier.

Comment: What I really need is a way to wait upon the completion of the api call and then login if the credentials are correct. The completion handler is in a different class and I can’t programmatically move to a new storyboard from the api class.

Comment: Then use the completion handler API. It’s a much easier way to do this. Give your API method a completion handler closure, so that the caller can specify what should happen if the network request succeeds. You can do this with delegate based sessions, but it’s a lot more complicated and we’d generally only go down that rabbit hole if absolutely necessary, which is not the case here.

Comment: I’m playing around with completion handlers, but having a tough time. Could you point to an example of setting a completion handler in one class and executing it in another?

Comment: I’ve added some examples to the end of my answer. Obviously the specifics won’t match your situation (you didn’t share details on how requests should be prepared, how responses should be parsed, etc.), but it illustrates the basic idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you technically can have a separate object be the delegate for the session. But it doesn’t make much sense to instantiate a view controller for this, for a few reasons:

1. Your code is creating a view controller instance as the delegate object, but you’re handing this off to the `URLSession` without keeping a reference to it. Thus, there’s no way to add this to the view controller hierarchy (e.g. to present it, to push to it, perform a segue to it, whatever).

   Sure, you might be presenting another instance of this view controller elsewhere, but that will be a completely separate instance, with no connection to the one you just created here. You’d end up with two separate `CreateAccountViewController` objects.
2. From an architectural perspective, many would argue that network delegate code doesn’t really belong in view controllers, anyway. View controllers are for populating views and responding to user events, not for network code.

So, in short, while you technically can have your API manager class use a separate object for the delegate calls, that’s a bit unusual. And if you did do that, you certainly wouldn’t create a `UIViewController` subclass for that.

A more common pattern (if you use the delegate pattern at all) might be to make the API manager, itself, the delegate for its `URLSession`. (Adding a separate dedicate delegate object in the mix probably only complicates the situation.) But by keeping all of this network-specific code out of the view controllers, you abstract your view controllers away from the gory details of parsing network responses, handling all of the various delegate methods, etc.

---

All of this begs the question: Do you really need to use the delegate-based API? It’s critical in those rare cases where you need the rich delegate API (handling custom challenge responses, etc.), but in most cases, the simple completion handler rendition of dataTask is much easier.

Give your API method a completion handler closure, so that the caller can specify what should happen if the network request succeeds. You can do this with delegate based sessions, but it’s a lot more complicated and we’d generally only go down that rabbit hole if absolutely necessary, which is not the case here.

So a common pattern would be to give your API manager (which I’ll assume is a singleton) a `login` method, like so:

```
/// Perform login request
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - userid: Userid string.
///   - password: Password string
///   - completion: Calls with `.success(true)` if successful. Calls `.failure(Error)` on error.
///
/// - Returns: The `URLSessionTask` of the network request (in case caller wants to cancel request).

@discardableResult
func login(userid: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void) -> URLSessionTask {
    let request = ... // Build your `URLRequest` here

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard
            error == nil,
            let responseData = data,
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            200 ..< 300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode
        else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(.failure(error ?? APIManagerError.invalidResponse(data, response))) }
            return
        }

        // parse `responseData` here

        let success = true

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if success {
                completion(.success(true))
            } else {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    return task
}
```

Where you might have a custom error class like so:

```
enum APIManagerError: Error {
    case invalidResponse(Data?, URLResponse?)
    case loginFailed(String)
}
```

And you’d call it like so:

```
APIManager.shared.login(userid: userid, password: password) { result in
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        // update UI to reflect error
        print(error)

    case .success:
        // do whatever you want if the login was successful
    }
}
```

Below is a more complete example, where I’ve broken up the network code down a bit (one to perform network requests, one generic method for parsing JSON, one specific method to parse the JSON associated with login), but the idea is still the same. When you perform an asynchronous method, give the method an `@escaping` completion handler closure which is called when the asynchronous task is done.

```
final class APIManager {
    static let shared = APIManager()

    private var session: URLSession

    private init() {
        session = .shared
    }

    let baseURLString = "https://example.com"

    enum APIManagerError: Error {
        case invalidResponse(Data?, URLResponse?)
        case loginFailed(String)
    }

    /// Perform network request with `Data` response.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - request: The `URLRequest` to perform.
    ///   - completion: Calls with `.success(Data)` if successful. Calls `.failure(Error)` on error.
    ///
    /// - Returns: The `URLSessionTask` of the network request (in case caller wants to cancel request).

    @discardableResult
    func perform(_ request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) -> URLSessionTask {
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard
                error == nil,
                let responseData = data,
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                200 ..< 300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode
            else {
                completion(.failure(error ?? APIManagerError.invalidResponse(data, response)))
                return
            }

            completion(.success(responseData))
        }

        task.resume()
        return task
    }

    /// Perform network request with JSON response.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - request: The `URLRequest` to perform.
    ///   - completion: Calls with `.success(Data)` if successful. Calls `.failure(Error)` on error.
    ///
    /// - Returns: The `URLSessionTask` of the network request (in case caller wants to cancel request).

    @discardableResult
    func performJSON<T: Decodable>(_ request: URLRequest, of type: T.Type, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) -> URLSessionTask {
        return perform(request) { result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))

            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(responseObject))
                } catch let parseError {
                    completion(.failure(parseError))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// Perform login request
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - userid: Userid string.
    ///   - password: Password string
    ///   - completion: Calls with `.success()` if successful. Calls `.failure(Error)` on error.
    ///
    /// - Returns: The `URLSessionTask` of the network request (in case caller wants to cancel request).

    @discardableResult
    func login(userid: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void) -> URLSessionTask {
        struct ResponseObject: Decodable {
            let success: Bool
            let message: String?
        }

        let request = prepareLoginRequest(userid: userid, password: password)

        return performJSON(request, of: ResponseObject.self) { result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))

            case .success(let responseObject):
                if responseObject.success {
                    completion(.success(true))
                } else {
                    completion(.failure(APIManagerError.loginFailed(responseObject.message ?? "Unknown error")))
                }
                print(responseObject)
            }
        }
    }

    private func prepareLoginRequest(userid: String, password: String) -> URLRequest {
        var components = URLComponents(string: baseURLString)!
        components.query = "login"
        components.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "userid", value: userid),
            URLQueryItem(name: "password", value: password)
        ]

        var request = URLRequest(url: components.url!)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        return request
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better is to don't do this by delegating other class in URL Session case ... return data in completion handler and access that in your class

And for data you can use other method

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, 
                dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, 
              didReceive data: Data)
```

Here you will get received data

Comment: Are you saying I can set that function in my view controller class and set it to be called in the completion handler? How would I force it to be called in the completion handler?